# How to increment a value on hosts (Ansible)

Tags: ansible

I have endless kafka servers to configure, their ids must be different from each other. Configuration must be done through jinja templating.

Their broker.id field should start from 0 to infinity if there are infinite number of servers.

```
# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id={{ broker_id }}
```

Expected on the conf files:

server1

```
broker.id=0
```

server2

```
broker.id=1
```

serverN

```
broker.id=N-1
```

**EDIT**

main.yml

```
---

- include: install.yml
  tags:
    - kafka
    - install

- include: config.yml
  tags:
    - kafka
    - config
```

config.yml

```
---

- name: server properties
  template:
    src: server.properties
    dest: /opt/kafka/config/server.properties

- name: zookeeper properties
  template:
    src: zookeeper.properties
    dest: /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
```

defaults/main.yml

```
---
#server.properties
broker_id: 0
```

templates/server.properties

```
.
.
.

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id={{ broker_id }}

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################
.
.
.
```

Ansible is applying same configuration to multiple servers, as normal behavior. But while applying same configuration broker.id must be unique.

```
{{ 99999999 | random | to_uuid }}
```

This is working, still i'm curious if it's possible to assign 0 to broker.id and increment +1 on each server?

Comment: Please post your playbook what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Add below

```
- name: Set Broker ID
  set_fact:
     broker_id: {{ groups['all'].index(inventory_hostname) }}
```

followed by other tasks.

Answer (score 1):

May be this helps

```
- name: Set Broker ID
  set_fact:
     broker_id: {{ ansible_play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just added

```
broker.id={{ groups['kafka'].index(inventory_hostname) | int + 1 }}
```

to my server.properties.j2 template and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create the inventory dynamically in the first play and use it in the second play. For example the playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    no_of_servers: 3
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "srv-{{ item }}"
        groups: kafka
        id: "{{ my_idx }}"
      loop: "{{ range(0, no_of_servers)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

- hosts: kafka
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} id: {{ id }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [srv-0] => {
    "msg": "srv-0 id: 0"
}
ok: [srv-1] => {
    "msg": "srv-1 id: 1"
}
ok: [srv-2] => {
    "msg": "srv-2 id: 2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think it will solve

```
broker.id={{ (inventory_hostname.split('0')[-1] | int) }}
```